# Set of image views not fitting for the landscape mode

Tags: android, imageview, orientation, landscape

I have a set of 10 image views that need to be set on the top of screen. In the portrait mode, it is perfect as per the requirement. But when I turn the screen orientation to landscape, the number of images remains same but width wise not fitting to the layout. I mean set of 10 image views fills only 50% of the screen.

I tried in many different ways, but still I am not able to do it for landscape

Here is my xml say main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:id="@+id/progresslayout" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>


<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pb3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb8"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

 <ImageView android:src="@drawable/progressgreen" android:id="@+id/pb10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried giving    android:layout_weight=" " property also but still no use. And interesting thing I noticed here is instead of image view, if I try the same thing with some button or edit text filed, it works fine for both portrait and landscape

Comment: your Linearlayout width and height should also be like android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: @Padma Kumar, I have tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progresslayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pb10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Remember to replace  `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"`  with your image resource. This will create ten images on top the screen nicely spacing between each other.

If you don't want space between images, use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` property for each images. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried this.In this case, the images fit but the image is not visible. If I give weight as 0 or 0.2, instead of 1, then images appear but not getting fit to the layout

Comment: Have u tried with other images? I had tested before posting here.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with other images. This happens only for image views, for fields like edit text or button this works

Comment: What i meant is this resource `@drawable/progressgreen` . In my code, i use `@drawable/ic_launcher`. It works fine.

Comment: Yeah I understood, but the this remains same as before for me. The image does not appear if I give weight as 1, but I can see the presence of the images. Did u try with exactly 10 set of images. Because I want the same number of images to be fit to the layout in both portrait and landscape

Comment: And if I see in the portrait mode, size is not proper

Comment: Hey, this is working now. I don't know why it din't work first. I added android:scaleType="fitXY" this later

Answer (score 0):

In the Linearlayout tag remove

> android:orientation="horizontal"

attribute and change

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Try it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. This will make sure that all objects share the whole layout width and each takes the same space.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progresslayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 // Your ImageViews Here
    <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/pb10"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:src="@drawable/image1" >  
    </ImageView>  

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: parent of the inner linear layout should be Relative Layout only

Comment: may i know why its necessary? and are you talking about the layout contain 10 images?

Comment: No, I am talking about the outermost linear layout which contains the inner layout. This is just a part of the whole layout. Many other things are associated with the outer Relative Layout, so it is necessary

Comment: then put Relative Layout above that outer Linear Layout means keeping the same code write RelativeLayout on top and give height width fill_parent